# How to preserve text transform formatting applied to input box?

Tags: html, css

I am applying some formatting to input made inside a text box in a web page.

```
 <input style="text-transform: uppercase"
      type="text"
      class="textbox"
      id="code"
      name="code"
      D_LABEL="code"
      beanProperty="code"
      value=""
      D_MANDATORY="true"
      maxlength="10"/>
```

This works fine. I am saving the value in a database. However the value saved is not in upper case. How do save the same value as it appears on the text box at the time of capture?

Comment: whatever server side language is being used to store the text in the database should be used to manipulate the data before storing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answers point you in the right direction . You can simply convert the input box text to uppercase in javascript before sending the data to server. Use `<string>.toUpperCase()` method to achieve the conversion

Comment: This will likely work for personal use cases.  However, if you are concerned about security, all validation must happen server side.  It is way too easy for someone to bypass client side validation.  All you need to do in this case is turn off javascript.

Comment: @evan : Yes , that is true. In that case , after getting the data , the server must convert into uppercase . That is a solution too.

Answer (score 5):

It will not be uppercase, the text is lowercase, or case-dependent on how it is entered, CSS simply manipulates the *visual* layer, **not the data**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guarantee this on the client side.  You need to perform string manipulation on the server side.

PHP Example:

```
$input = $_POST["code"];
$val = strtoupper($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between 'value' and 'presentation'. The value stays as it was – it is only presented by CSS in uppercase. If you need an uppercase value, you'll need to transform it after transferring to the server.